# SQL to convert TimeZone of TimeStamp column from A to B when system is in TimeZone C

Tags: sql, oracle, timezone

`BirthDatabase` table in Oracle 11g has following five columns:

1. `ID` - Not Null - Number
2. `Name` - Varchar2(32)
3. `DOB` - Date
4. `Place` - Varchar2(32)
5. `BirthTime` - TimeStamp(6)

`BirthTime` column is not TimeZone aware but has DateTime data which is in `UTC`.

However, (most importantly) system timestamp for Database is in `Europe\London`.

This implies that `BirthTime` data is not `timezone` aware and is in a different TZ as compared to system TZ.

**Task:** write a SQL query to fetch `BirthTime` in London local time (i.e., UTC when DST is OFF and UTC+1 when DST is ON)

My approach:

I have tried to play with `cast` function in SQL but didn't quite achieve the desired output

```
select
    ID, Name, DOB, Place,
    BirthTime as orig_BT,
    cast(BirthTime as timestamp with time zone) as BT_withTz, 
    cast(cast(BirthTime as timestamp with time zone) at time zone 'Europe/London' as timestamp) BT_BST,
    cast(cast(BirthTime as timestamp with time zone) at time zone 'UTC' as timestamp) BT_UTC
from
    BirthDatabase
```

This returns the following output:

```
ID  NAME    DOB         PLACE   ORIG_BT                         BT_WITHTZ                                   BT_BST                          BT_UTC
________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________
1   John    28-OCT-16   Bristol 28-OCT-16 10.48.12.000000000    28-OCT-16 10.48.12.000000000 EUROPE/LONDON  28-OCT-16 10.48.12.000000000    28-OCT-16 09.48.12.000000000
2   Jane    01-NOV-16   London  01-NOV-16 11.48.29.000000000    01-NOV-16 11.48.29.000000000 EUROPE/LONDON  01-NOV-16 11.48.29.000000000    01-NOV-16 11.48.29.000000000
```

My desired output is following:

```
ID  NAME    DOB         PLACE   ORIG_BT                         BT_DESIRED
____________________________________________________________________________________________
1   John    28-OCT-16   Bristol 28-OCT-16 10.48.12.000000000    28-OCT-16 11.48.12.000000000
2   Jane    01-NOV-16   London  01-NOV-16 11.48.29.000000000    01-NOV-16 11.48.29.000000000
```

I think one of the quick and dirty way to get *Desired output* using the output of above query is to modify the SQL to compute the following:

```
BT_DESRIED = ORIG_BT + (BT_BST - BT_UTC)
```

My question are as follows:

1. What is the syntax to compute above expression of `BT_DESRIED = ORIG_BT + (BT_BST - BT_UTC)`
2. Is there a more elegant way to achieve this?

Comment: There are more elegant ways - Oracle has a large number of timestamp functions to convert from one timezone to another. The biggest problem I can see right now is that you want to infer the timezone of the ORIG_BT from the PLACE. So you will need a helper table to tell you what timezone should be used for each PLACE. (And there will be complications - what time zone designation was used in that place AT THAT TIME? Did they use DST THEN? etc.)

Comment: `BirthTime`\ORIG_BT is not tz aware but the data in that column is in UTC. There is no interpretation required from Place. I believe DST should not cause any problem as long as the function can convert from one tz to another.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following query:

```
select
   ID, Name, DOB, Place, BirthTime as orig_BT,
   FROM_TZ(BirthTime, 'UTC') AT TIME ZONE 'Europe/London' AS BT_BST
FROM BirthDatabase;
```

When you make `cast(BirthTime as timestamp with time zone)` the Oracle takes your **`SESSIONTIMEZONE`** for conversion - not the database system time zone.

`cast(BirthTime as timestamp with time zone) at time zone 'Europe/London'` will give correct results when you execute `alter session set time_zone = 'UTC';` beforehand.

Comment: That is indeed the solution I was looking for. Thanks @Wernfried

Answer (score 1):

My server is in time zone `AMERICA/CHICAGO`. In the example below, assume the timestamp `ts` is given (with no time zone). The second value I select is the same timestamp, with my server's time zone attached.

If you want to treat it as though it was meant to represent a different time zone, not the server's time zone, you can do so with the `FROM_TZ()` function - see the third expression I selected. And then you can convert from the `NEW YORK` time zone to the `LONDON` time zone with the `AT TIME ZONE` modifier (fourth value). I show the values one below the other to fit in the window (of course on screen they will be in one very long row). Also, the formatting of timestamps uses my current settings - they may look different on your machine, or use `to_char()` with explicit format models.

```
select ts, 
       cast(ts as timestamp with time zone)                         as ts_at_server_tz,
       from_tz(ts, 'America/New_York')                              as ts_at_NY_tz,
       from_tz(ts, 'America/New_York') at time zone 'Europe/London' as ts_at_LN_tz
from   ( 
         select to_timestamp('2000-01-15 14:30:00', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') as ts 
         from   dual 
       )
;


TS                              
------------------------------- 
15-JAN-00 02.30.00.000000000 PM

TS_AT_SERVER_TZ                        
----------------------------------------------- 
15-JAN-00 02.30.00.000000000 PM AMERICA/CHICAGO 

TS_AT_NY_TZ                            
-------------------------------------- ---------
15-JAN-00 02.30.00.000000000 PM AMERICA/NEW_YORK


TS_AT_LN_TZ
---------------------------------------------
15-JAN-00 07.30.00.000000000 PM EUROPE/LONDON
```